# Implement echo cancellation in audio recorder android

Tags: android, audiorecord

I am using AudioRecord class to read voice input.

```
public class AudioSession {
    private boolean isRecording=false;
    public  AudioRecord recorder;
    private int port          =50005;
    public String ipAddress="10.105.14.252";
    private int sampleRate    =AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);;
    private int channelConfig =AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    private int encodingFormat=AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int minBufSize=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    int bufferSize=0;
    DatagramSocket socket;
    public void startStreaming(){   
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public
        void run(){
            try{
                socket=new DatagramSocket();
                byte[] buffer=new byte[minBufSize];
                DatagramPacket packet;
                final InetAddress destination=InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
                recorder=new AudioRecord(MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,encodingFormat,minBufSize);
                if(recorder.getState()==AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)  
                    recorder.startRecording();

                while(isRecording){
                    bufferSize=recorder.read(buffer,0,minBufSize);
                    packet=new DatagramPacket(buffer,minBufSize,destination,port);
                    socket.send(packet);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

and at server side
I am receiving it and giving it as output to speakers

```
class Server {

static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat audioFormat;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 44100; 
static SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
static boolean streaming = true;
static int i = 0;
static Queue<InetAddress> q = new LinkedList<InetAddress>();
private static InetAddress currentSpeakerAddress;
static Set<InetAddress> h = new HashSet<InetAddress>();
public static final String PERMISSION_TEXT = "You may start talking";

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    while (true) {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[8192];

        audioFormat = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem
                .getLine(new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,
                        audioFormat));
        sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine.start();

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);
        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                receivePacket.getData());

        while (streaming == true) {
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String requestText = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            InetAddress requestAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            if (i == 0) {
                currentSpeakerAddress = requestAddress;
                notifyToTalk(currentSpeakerAddress);
            }
            if (requestText.contains("Raise Hand")) {
                if (currentSpeakerAddress.equals(requestAddress)) {
                    System.out.println(requestAddress.getHostAddress()
                            + " is online");
                } else {
                    storeID(requestAddress);
                }
            } else if (requestText.contains("Withdraw")) {
                if (currentSpeakerAddress.equals(requestAddress)) {
                    if (h.isEmpty()) {
                        // break;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    // currentSpeakerAddress = getNext();
                } else {
                    if (h.remove(requestAddress)) {
                        q.remove(requestAddress);
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentSpeakerAddress.equals(requestAddress)) {
                ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, audioFormat,
                        receivePacket.getLength());
                toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println(i++ + " " + receivePacket.getLength());
            }
        }
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    }
}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {
        sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
    }
}
}
```

but using this,
there is a lot of echo
I read somewhere to use short[], but sourceDataLine and Datagram uses byte[] to write.
What should I do so that it could work even for API less than 11...

Comment: Short vs byte isn't going to make a difference.  Echo is probably an issue with the data from the microphone itself.  To check, throw it through a standard media player as a wav file.  My bet is you still hear it.  You can do post-processing echo cancelation, but you'll need to research audio DSP algorithms-  its not an easy thing to write.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on the DSP level, you can check the hexagon SDK. I think it requires some extra licensing.